# is there a way to set an asp.net session variable from a javascript/jquery link?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, session

Basically i am trying to set a session when a user clicks a specific button is this possible?

So i need to set this session

```
Session("TenHolStDateNewCheck") = "%"
```

When this link is clicked

```
<a href="availability.aspx" class="sidelink">blahblah</a>
```

thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with a ajax call to a page that sets the session variable of choice to whaterver you send along with the ajax call

See: [`jQquery Ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

Comment: I really have to say that Branimir's answer has more information and should really be the accepted one or at least get an up vote

Answer (score 18):

You need a server side code to set session, use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) function

[Using jQuery with ASP.NET](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/jquery/jquerypart2.aspx)

You can use something like this:

Server side (C#)

```
public partial class _Default : Page 
{
  [WebMethod]
  public static void SetSession()
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Client side (aspx)

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Default.aspx/SetSession",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function() {
    alert('SetSession executed.');
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't really understand how to do this can you give an example

Comment: Look at examples on linked site

Comment: This worked great even after these years thanks @Branimir

Answer (score 0):

You can implement JSON-RPC `set_session_var` method and then in JQuery with $.ajax send json-rpc request to `set_session_var` method.